# Programmatically display 2 applications side by side in Windows 10 tablet mode

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

I'm trying to display 2 applications side by side using the windows 10 tablet mode feature. An always on top menu will open the 2 applications. The problem is that I can't automatically display the 2 apps side by side. I am usin Process.Start() to launch applications.

Steps:

1. Open App1 via always on top menu (Store)

2. Open App2 via always on top menu (Edge)

What I want is when the second application is launched, it will be displayed side by side using the tablet mode feature. I already tried PInvoke to set the position of the 2 applications and display the divider. I also tried to use the UWP API LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView but it is not working when called in WPF.